# Top aligned nested math environmnets

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

How can I make `y_* =` appear on the same level as the first line of `aligned` environment without `delarray` package?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareMathOperator{\const}{\mathop{C}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
y_* &=
    \begin{aligned}
        \const_{10}e^{\lambda_1 x}+\const_{11}xe^{\lambda_1 x}+\const_{12}x^2e^{\lambda_1 x}&\\
        +&\const_{20}e^{\lambda_2 x} \>=
    \end{aligned}
    \\[2ex]
&=
    \begin{aligned}
        1+x+x^2&\\
        +&e^{-x}
    \end{aligned}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The definition of `\const` is wrong. It should be simply `\newcommand{\const}{\mathrm{C}}`. At least remove `\mathop`, which lowers the C with no reason to.

Comment: @egreg Interesting to know. Actually, I've looked up somewhere such a declaration of math operators. When do you need `\mathop` then?

Comment: Hardly ever in the context of `\DeclareMathOperator`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `t` option from the `aligned` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareMathOperator{\const}{\mathop{C}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
y_* &=
    \begin{aligned}[t]
        \const_{10}e^{\lambda_1 x}+\const_{11}xe^{\lambda_1 x}+\const_{12}x^2e^{\lambda_1 x}&\\
        +&\const_{20}e^{\lambda_2 x} \>=
    \end{aligned}
    \\[2ex]
&=
    \begin{aligned}[t]
        1+x+x^2&\\
        +&e^{-x}
    \end{aligned}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]